# Adding navbar to centred elements using display property

Tags: html, css

I am trying to centre and overall set elements using css `display` property but i encountered a problem.

Once i added a navbar as an element whole structure got changed it's place.

Here is the code before i added navbar:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3F4E62;
}

.article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.item{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Georgia;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content"><div class="menu"><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a></div><div class="article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean iaculis non eros pellentesque
        commodo. Phasellus elit mauris, ultricies ac sem volutpat, efficitur convallis nibh. Mauris rutrum
        odio nec justo rutrum, sit amet tristique sapien tristique. Nullam ac urna eget tortor suscipit blandit.
        Maecenas pharetra faucibus odio quis feugiat. Curabitur a commodo arcu, a pellentesque lorem.
        Nulla facilisi. Nullam augue metus, scelerisque sed pulvinar at, fermentum sit amet arcu. Morbi
        lobortis suscipit porttitor. In vel tristique lorem, vitae pulvinar sapien. Nullam pretium imperdiet
        nibh, eu bibendum arcu egestas ac. Vestibulum faucibus fringilla justo. Nam facilisis
        elementum ex, ut fermentum leo feugiat vulputate. Ut molestie, enim ac faucibus mollis, est turpis
        varius lectus, at sollicitudin erat ligula vitae tortor. Ut tincidunt sed sem in sodales. Cras tincidunt
        ligula diam, quis volutpat quam cursus nec.
        </div></div>
```

Navbar was supposed to be a line across whole window but it got stuck inline with elements from div with `class="content"`.

Here is the code when i added navbar:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3F4E62;
}

.article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.item{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: Georgia;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">Navbar</div>
<div class="content"><div class="menu"><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a></div><div class="article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean iaculis non eros pellentesque
        commodo. Phasellus elit mauris, ultricies ac sem volutpat, efficitur convallis nibh. Mauris rutrum
        odio nec justo rutrum, sit amet tristique sapien tristique. Nullam ac urna eget tortor suscipit blandit.
        Maecenas pharetra faucibus odio quis feugiat. Curabitur a commodo arcu, a pellentesque lorem.
        Nulla facilisi. Nullam augue metus, scelerisque sed pulvinar at, fermentum sit amet arcu. Morbi
        lobortis suscipit porttitor. In vel tristique lorem, vitae pulvinar sapien. Nullam pretium imperdiet
        nibh, eu bibendum arcu egestas ac. Vestibulum faucibus fringilla justo. Nam facilisis
        elementum ex, ut fermentum leo feugiat vulputate. Ut molestie, enim ac faucibus mollis, est turpis
        varius lectus, at sollicitudin erat ligula vitae tortor. Ut tincidunt sed sem in sodales. Cras tincidunt
        ligula diam, quis volutpat quam cursus nec.
        </div></div>
```

Comment: You have the body `{display: flex;}` remove that.

Comment: It will break centring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the body tag and add another `div class="main-container">` *name it whatever you want* with the following style. You're missing the `flex-flow:` or `flex-wrap` so the elements are not wrapping and you basically need them to wrap.

```
.main-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Here check this:

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 1px;
  justify-content: center;
}

.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-width: 1px;
  background-color: #000000;
  display: block;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #3f4e62;
}

.article {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 380px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.item {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Georgia;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="nav">Navbar</div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="menu"><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a><a class="item">MENU ITEM</a></div>
    <div class="article">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean iaculis non eros pellentesque commodo. Phasellus elit mauris, ultricies ac sem volutpat, efficitur convallis nibh. Mauris rutrum odio nec justo rutrum, sit amet tristique sapien tristique.
      Nullam ac urna eget tortor suscipit blandit. Maecenas pharetra faucibus odio quis feugiat. Curabitur a commodo arcu, a pellentesque lorem. Nulla facilisi. Nullam augue metus, scelerisque sed pulvinar at, fermentum sit amet arcu. Morbi lobortis suscipit
      porttitor. In vel tristique lorem, vitae pulvinar sapien. Nullam pretium imperdiet nibh, eu bibendum arcu egestas ac. Vestibulum faucibus fringilla justo. Nam facilisis elementum ex, ut fermentum leo feugiat vulputate. Ut molestie, enim ac faucibus
      mollis, est turpis varius lectus, at sollicitudin erat ligula vitae tortor. Ut tincidunt sed sem in sodales. Cras tincidunt ligula diam, quis volutpat quam cursus nec.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I went for adding `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the body instead of creating new element to wrap which works great. Thanks a lot for mentioning `flex-wrap: wrap;`